# Group of nonsingular 2x2 matrices

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $GL(2, \mathbb R)$ denote the group of all nonsingular $2 \times 2$ matrices over $\mathbb R$. Show that each of the following sets is a subgroup of $GL(2, \mathbb R).$

$(a)\quad S = \left\{\begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ c & d\end{bmatrix}\mid a, b, c, d \in \mathbb R \;\text{and}\;ad-bc = 1\right\}.$

$(b)\quad S = \left\{\begin{bmatrix} a & 0\\ 0 & a\end{bmatrix}\mid a \in \mathbb R \text{ and } a\neq 0\right\}.$

A group is a set with an operation attached to it. What exactly does $GL(2, \mathbb{R})$ mean? What is the operation here?

I suppose the question states: Let $GL(2, \mathbb{R})$ denote a group with ALL $2 \times 2$ matrices EXCEPT the identity matrix $\begin{smallmatrix} 1 & 0 \\\ 0 & 1 \end{smallmatrix}$.

Show that the following is a subgroup of that group...? Right? But I need an operation to complete this problem. What am I misunderstanding?

Comment: $\left(\begin{smallmatrix} 1 & 0 \\\ 0 & 1 \end{smallmatrix}\right)$ is included in $GL(2,{\Bbb{R}})$

Comment: "Non-singular" here means "invertible", i.e. $GL(2,\Bbb R)$ is the set of all $2\times 2$ matrices that have an inverse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

${\bf GL}(\color{blue}{2}, \color{red}{\mathbb R})$ is called the *$\bf{G}$eneral $\bf L$inear group*  consisting of $\color{blue}{2} \times \color{blue}2$ ***invertible*** matrices with $\color{red}{\text{real}}$ valued entries.

The group operation is matrix multiplication.

$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$ IS included in $GL(2\mathbb R)$. Indeed, it is the identity element in $GL(2 \mathbb R)$.

In (a), you are being asked to show that the set of all $2\times 2$ matrices whose determinant is $1$ is a subgroup of $GL(2, \mathbb R)$.

In (b), you are being asked to show that all $2\times 2$ diagonal matrices (whose entries on the diagonal are non-zero) is a subgroup of $GL(2, \mathbb R)$.

Comment: Also note that the group is not Abelian.

Comment: How did you know that the group operation was matrix multiplication?

Comment: That's precisely the operation that defines the general linear groups, including $GL(2 \mathbb R)$. You simply need to confirm that the identity matrix is in each of your subgroups, that the "subgroups" are closed under matrix multiplication, and that the inverse of each matrix in each of your subgroups is also in that subgroup (recall that each matrix in $GL(2, \mathbb R)$ is invertible).

Comment: Thank you. That clears it up.

Comment: You're welcome!

Comment: Did you mean "...and that the inverse of each matrix in your subgroups is in your GROUP"?

Comment: I mean to deal with each of the proposed subgroups individually. Each matrix in (a) has an inverse, but you need to make sure that its inverse is also in (a). Same with (b).

Comment: Ah, thanks. I see now.

Answer (score 1):

The operation you need is the standard [multiplication of matrices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication#Matrix_product_.28two_matrices.29):

$$\left(\begin{matrix} a & b \\\ c & d \end{matrix}\right)\left(\begin{matrix} a' & b' \\\ c' & d' \end{matrix}\right)=\left(\begin{matrix} aa'+bc' & ab'+bd' \\\ ca'+dc' & cb'+dd' \end{matrix}\right)$$

$GL(2,\mathbb{R})$ is the set of *invertible* matrices, meaning that $A$ is invertible if there exist a $B$ such that $AB=\operatorname{I}$, where $\operatorname{I}=\left(\begin{matrix} 1 & 0 \\\ 0 & 1 \end{matrix}\right)$. You need to check first that $GL(2,\mathbb{R})$ with this operation is a group, and the you have to show that those two are subgroups, i.e. they are closed under multiplication and inverse.